# HCS12 Assembly Arithmetic

Tags: assembly

so I am learning assembly for the HCS12 microcontroller.

I need to evaluate the expression `-45+6+(13*2)-(7*4)-65+33`.
The expression needs to be evaluated left to right, following standard order of operations. Each operation needs to be performed on byte values, and I can only use addition, subtraction, and shifts.

I can evaluate `-45+6+(13*2)-(7*4)` fine, but problems arise when I try to subtract 65 from -41. I understand what's going on, I just don't know how to work around it.

**edit**: I should be more clear, I know what is happening (the values are being truncated). I just don't know why.

**edit2**: Solved! The line `ldab #Term5` should be `ldab Term5` (Same thing with the next line)

Here's the code I'm using, for reference:

```
; local defines
            TERM3:  EQU 13
            TERM4:  EQU 07
;********************************************************************
MyConst:    SECTION
; Place constant data here
ConstData:  DC.B  -45,16
Term5:      DC.B  65
Term6:      DC.B  33
;********************************************************************
MyCode:     SECTION
main:
Entry:
            lds #__SEG_END_SSTACK     ; initialize the stack pointer
            sei                       ; disable interrupts
; Program code goes here
main_loop:
            nop
            ldx   #ConstData          ; load -45 and 16 into x
            ldaa  0,x                 ; load -45 from x to a
            ldab  1,x                 ; load 16 from x to b
            aba                       ; add b to a (a=(-39))
            ldab  #TERM3              ; load 13 into b
            aslb                      ; shift b left (multiply by 2)
            aba                       ; add b to a (a=(-13))
            ldab  #TERM4              ; load 7 into b
            aslb                      ; shift b left (multiply by 2)
            asl                       ; shift b left (multiply by 2)
            sba                       ; subtract b from a (a=(-41))
            ldab  #Term5              ; Issues start here.
            subb  #Term6
            aba
            nop
            END
;********************************************************************
```

Comment: You understand why?  Can you enlighten us?

Comment: _"problems arise ... "_. What kind of problems?

Comment: Basically, when I try to load 65 into register B, the value gets truncated. In another version of the code, where I use `suba #Term5` the value also ends up getting truncated to one byte. Because of how new I am to assembly, I don't know how to work around this.

Comment: Truncated how? `A` and `B` are only 8 bits each, but I assume you already know that. That's still enough to represent any signed number in the range -128..+127.

Comment: That's what I'm not understanding. When I compile the code, I end up with the following warning: `A12003: Value is truncated to one byte`. I have no idea why this happens, because `A` and `B` **should** be capable of holding the value, no problem.

Comment: Does it say which line the warning is for?

Comment: Yes, the warning is on this instruction: `ldab  #Term5`.

Comment: Figured it out! Turns out that when loading constants, you don't need a `#` sign. So `ldab #Term5` should actually be `ldab Term5`.

Answer (score 1):

(Self-answered question.)

Per the comments:

> Figured it out! Turns out that when loading constants, you don't need a `#` sign. So `ldab #Term5` should actually be `ldab Term5`. – dfryer1193 Sep 3 '13 at 16:32